# 'Prototype' throws TypeError: info is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am trying to inherit a function by prototype, it seems all are correct (according to me), but I am getting error... any one help me to understand this issue?

function:

```
(function($){
    var Man = function(info){
        this.name = info.name;
        this.age = info.age;
        this.work = info.work;
    }

    Man.prototype.tell = function(){
        return 'I am Mr.' + this.name;
    }

    var Dog = function(info){
        Man.call(this,info);
    }

    Dog.prototype = new Man();

    var dog1 = new Dog({name:'Dobber',age:3,work:'roming'});
    console.log(dog1.tell());

})($);
```

error I am getting:

```
TypeError: info is undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `new Man()` setting up the `Dog` prototype, you're not passing an argument. The function expects one (that's what `info` is supposed to be).

I'm not sure how to correct it because the setup in that code doesn't make a lot of sense.

*edit* — maybe just make the `Man` constructor check the parameter:

```
function Man(info) {
  if (info !== undefined) {
    this.name = info.name;
    this.age = info.age;
    this.work = info.work;
  }
}
```

Comment: what the if condition exactly do here?

Comment: @3gwebtrain it just checks to see if a parameter was actually passed to the function.  That way, when you set up the "Dog" prototype with a call to "Man" but with no "info" argument, you won't get an exception.

Comment: The idiomatic correction would be to not call the constructor when setting up the inheritance. You do this with `Object.create`, and adding a shim if needed. `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Man);`

Comment: @thesystem yes I agree; I was trying to work with what's there, but overall I don't think that's a really good approach.